# Why Magento doesn't change the product prices if a customer choosen another Payment Method?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, product-prices

```
public function paymentEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $this->log("Entramos al observer");
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($cartItems as $item) {
  $newPrice = $this->getNewPrice($item->getPrice()); // Function that calculate the newPrice (%)
  $item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
  $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
  $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
  $item->save();

}
$this->log("Observer END");
return $this;
```

}

This function change the product prices depending the payment Method selected.

**Observer Method Event:**  sales_quote_payment_import_data_before

But if for some reason the customer changes his payment method, the prices keeps at the same amount.

**Example:** first i choose Payment Method Y and works ok, but if for some reason i need to changa the payment method and i go back to step 4 and now i choose payment method Z, all the calculates are made with the payment method Y, i need again to go back to step 4 and choose again Payment Method Z and now it shows the prices ok.

Theres any form to flush the payment method choosen if the customer go back to step 4 or another one?

Comment: did you verify that, you get recent selection of payment methods when observer called?

Comment: Yes i have a log file, there's shows that information, and looks everything ok. I don't know whats happening but if i change to another payment method i need to choose it twice. Because the firstone still haves the information of the firstime that i choosen the payment.

Answer (score 0):

First,  `sales_quote_payment_import_data_before` event  fire when `importData(array $data)` is called.

So, you need to change when you have changing the payment gateway that times,need to ensure that **`$QuoteObject->getPayment()->importData($data)`**  called.

Also after run `$item->save();`,you should called

> ```
> $quote->collectTotals()->save();
> ```

for **calculated total price and assign new price to quote**

Comment: `public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
         // my code is here 
    }`

I Change the observer for a Model Class which is executed after payment Method is selected.

My log file shows all ok, ut I still need 2 times to choose the payment method to update the view

Comment: Do u know wich event was executed after paymentMethod is choosen?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but had the same question / problem using observer `sales_quote_payment_import_data_before`...

the code uses the old payment method.

To get the new chosen method, you can use:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams()
```

You'll get:

```
[payment] => Array
    (
        [method] => method_code_chosen
    )
```